# Having trouble to change different sprite sheet on cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to change a different sprite sheet on my cocos2d project. 
And i was using spriteSheet.plist and it was working fine. For some reason, I need to add more sprite and change the file to spriteSheet2.plist
And i already include files like spriteSheet2.plist, spriteSheet2.pvr.ccz

But it ends up return a error msg
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
[CCSpriteFrameCache purgeSharedSpriteFrameCache];   
CCSpriteFrameCache *frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];   
//        [frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spriteSheet.plist" ];    
[frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"spriteSheet2.plist" ];
```

and other issue if i remove my original 'spritesheet.plist' from Xcode.  Sprits is still working on the screen.

would anyone tell what should I do to get ride of the error message?

Answer (score 2):

you have a batch node somewhere which was created with the first texture, to which you are trying to add sprites from the second texture. All sprites contained in a batch node must be from the same texture as the texture with which the batch node was created.

Comment: Someone ought to rephrase that error message to make it absolutely clear, "not using same texture id" is just … too factual perhaps. ;)

Comment: yes, that or 'sticky' questions on here. I would add a few on 'performance' myself. However, nothing like a 'global search' with your favourite IDE to go straight to the failing NSAssert in question.